# Inline declaration missing in header: Linker or Compiler Error?

Tags: c++, linker, compiler-construction, inline

After searching for an answer for a while, I am now even more confused than before...

I am wondering if I declare in the header file an inline function that is not implemented, but called in the main function, will this result in an linker or compiler error?

When I look at the error I get `undefined reference to 'A::a()'` it seems like a linker error.

However, in some discussions it says that the Compiler MUST see the function delcaration, therefore it would be an Compiler Error.

I hope you can tell me what I am getting wrong here :)

Header:
[image: Header]

Main function:
[image: Main function]

Comment: You have declared `A::a()` but have not defined it - you need to write what it does. Or just change it to `inline void a() {};` Note please post code and not images.

Comment: @RichardCritten The question is not about WHY this error is issued, but whose responsibility it is to report it - the linker or the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

It is a linker error in most compilers when you have a functon declaration, but the implementation (definition) of the function is not present.

Technically, the compiler MAY report that an `inline` function is not present in the source, but the compiler is not obliged to do so, and code exists that do not always define the function that is declared as inline. It is not, in most compilers, an error to declare a function inline, and define it in a separate compilation unit (different source file), so compilers do not give an error by default.

If the compiler doesn't find the definition for an inline function, the compiler will assume that it's an external function, and the linker is the only place were all of the code comes together, and thus "it's not there" is issued by the linker.

To clarify:

You may well have a situation where you want to declare as inline a function but put the implementation of a function in a source-file (perhaps because it's never called anywhere else, there is a single factory function to instantiate all instances of that class). Then it is perfectly legal to declare the function [such as a constructor] as inline in the header-file, and the place the implementation of the function in a source file, using the object in various other files without an implementation present.

In practice, compilers also allow the calling of inline functions, even when they are only declared in a source file, not the header. The compiler will not always inline those functions [in practice, only "link time optimization" or "whole program optimization" are likely to do that].

Comment: `It is not, per the standard, an error to declare a function inline, and define it in a separate compilation unit` [This](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.inline#:inline_function) seems to disagree? "An inline function or variable shall be defined in every translation unit in which it is odr-used"

Comment: It also allows external declarations of inline functions, and as far as I know, constructors are external "If a function or variable with external linkage is declared inline in one translation unit, it shall be declared inline in all translation units in which it appears; no diagnostic is required.
An inline function or variable with external linkage shall have the same address in all translation units"

Comment: @Mats: I don't see how the fact that an inline function may have external linkage relieves the programmer from the responsibility to define the function in every TU in which it is odr-used (with the same definition) as per the citation in usr657267's comment. Extern inline functions have a consistent address across all TU's in a program, but they still need to be defined in every TU which takes the address.

Comment: Ok, I'll remove the part about "according to the standard", since that appears to be controversial. It is certainly what every compiler developer [company or group, not persons] I'm aware of have NOT followed this principle, and I see no wording in the specification that says anything beyond "it has to be the same address each time" and "must be inline in every TU".

Answer (score -2):

It depends on the compiler you are using but as far as I remember an inline declaration is by default a recommendation to the compiler. In your case, since the compiler didn't find the implementation of the function it will not implement it inline and will leave it to the linker to link.

If you are using GCC you can force the compiler to do inline, see more details in this blog:

[Force inline functions in C++(GCC)](http://jijithchandran.blogspot.co.il/2013/12/force-inline-functions-in-cgcc.html)

Comment: Not really what the question is about.